# How to make a landscape with multiple materials?

Tags: materials, masking

I want to make a "big" landscape with various materials, which I have to place by hand (not only textures!). So, how could I do it? 
I heard about masking (?), but I never worked with it, so I'm not sure how to do it and if it's possible to do it with 6 different materials, not only 2 like I have seen it.

(I want to work with cycles)
Thank you

Comment: can you provide an example image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a landscape with multiple terrains (stone, grass field, snow, a path,...) but without harsh lines between them (there should be smooth transitions). I could make it with texture painting, but then I would loose the bump maps etc.and thats the problem. I think its hard to find a picture with that...

Comment: why would you lose the bump maps if you did texture painting? Anything you paint can be separated. So you could paint each material as a separate texture and paint a texture to be used as the bump map. Then in the Nodes editor use a Mix or Add node to combine them all.

Comment: Okay, I'm stupid...you are right. Thank you :)